# How do I persist the store using persistStore()? I am facing an error 'store does not have a valid reducer'

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, redux-persist

I believe I am correctly passing 'reducer' inside persistCombineReducers() along with 'config' to create a store that is persistent. But I face an error saying - 'store does not have a valid reducer'

```
import { createStore } from 'redux'
import { persistStore, persistCombineReducers } from 'redux-persist'
import storage from 'redux-persist/es/storage'

...


const reducer = (state=initialState, action) => {
  switch(action.type){
    ...
  }
}

...


export const store =
  createStore(persistCombineReducers(config, reducer), initialState)

export const persistor = persistStore(store)

...
```

I expect the store to be persistent. Rather it throws an error - "store does not have a valid reducer"

Comment: Are you refering the persist-store npm docs ? https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist

Comment: @SureshKumarAriya yes, Suresh! Any thoughts on this?

Comment: in persistCombineReducers(config, reducer) try replacing reducer with an object containing your reducers instead or replace the function with persistReducer (because you're not combining anything right now)

Comment: @hardworker Thanks a lot! I ain't aware of 'persistReducer' and it helped the cause

Comment: @DivyatejaDanny no problem :) i'll add it as an answer if anyone has the same problem

Answer (score 1):

Use `persistReducer` instead of `persistCombineReducers`.

`PersistReducer` is used when you have only 1 reducer, and ask a function as parameter, while `persistCombineReducers` ask an object as parameter (an object containing a list of reducers)